# Converting an optimisation problem to an integer linear formulation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

Is there a way to convert the following to a linear formulation? In other words, is there a workaround for the absolute value in the objective function?

Minimise: $\left|\textbf{$c^Tx$}\right|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i\right|$

subject to:

$x_i\in\{1,-1\}$ for all $i=1,...,n$

$c_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $i=1,...,n$

I know that if the objective function was $\sum_{i=1}^n|c_ix_i|$ there we could replace each $|x_i|$ with a difference of two positive variables (and I think add some constraints). Is there a similar technique here? Or perhaps a not-so-similar technique?

Comment: Replace the cost by a new variable $\alpha$ and add the linear constraints $\alpha \ge c^T x, \alpha \ge - c^T x$.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you mean that $\alpha=|c^Tx|$? So the objective function would just be minimise $\alpha$? Don't we need the objective function in the form $c^Tx$? Or do you mean that we introduce new variables $y$ so that $\alpha=c^Ty$ and then $y\geq x$ and $y\geq -x$?

Comment: You are now minimising over the variables $(\alpha, x)$. The objective $\alpha$ can be written as $\tilde{c}^T (\alpha, x^T)^T$.

Comment: @copper.hat So we minimise $\widetilde{c}_\alpha\alpha+\widetilde{c}_1x_1+\widetilde{c}_2x_2+\widetilde{c}_3x_3$? with constraints $\widetilde{c}_\alpha\alpha+\widetilde{c}_1x_1+\widetilde{c}_2x_2+\widetilde{c}_3x_3\geq c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$ and $\widetilde{c}_\alpha\alpha+\widetilde{c}_1x_1+\widetilde{c}_2x_2+\widetilde{c}_3x_3\geq -c_1x_1-c_2x_2-c_3x_3$ plus the original constraints?

Comment: @copper.hat for $n=3$.

Comment: No, the problem is to minimise $\alpha$ subject to the original constraints and the two additional constraints $\alpha \ge c^T x, \alpha \ge - x^T x$. I was just pointing out that the cost $\alpha$ can be written in the form $b^T y$.

Comment: @copper.hat ok thanks. And is $\alpha$ equal to the old objective or is it a whole new function? when you say replace the cost...

Comment: If you solve the modified problem then the minimising $\alpha$ is the value of the minimising cost of the original problem.